# pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL during installing anything with PIP command

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Whenever I am trying to install anything with pip I am getting an error:-

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

[image]

I am using

1. windows 10
2. Anaconda Python
3. Spyder IDE

I am a newbie in programming

Answer (score -1):

I see you have Anaconda Python. Thats is good but you can't use pip. You should use the conda command.  Use it like you would pip.  `conda install numpy` will install the numpy package on your machine,